# Python: Split in collection of data frames column with integers into single digit columns

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a collection of two data frames in a python dictionary. Each data frame has a string column consisting of a combination of zero and ones. Further the length of the string varies as the length is the number of days in that month.

My problem is that I cant figure out how to split the string column into many, so that in each column there is only a one or zero or a missing value.

I have seen the thread with the suggestion that a single number can be split into its digits by using `list(map(int(i) for i in str(01111001))`.

However how could I split the col Holiday in the dictionary below into many columns so that each column contains only a one or zero or a missing value if the particular record is shorter.

```
 'ATM':
  Plant           Year    Month Holiday
  01               1996   Mar   '01111001'
  02               1997   Feb   '0111011'
  SP               1996   Mar   '01100111'
  BE               1999   Mar   '00111111'

'FDA':
 Plant           Year     Month Holiday
  01               2001   Mar    '01111101'
  02               2002   Mar    '11110110' 
  SP               2001   Apr    '1110011' 
  BE               2002   June   '10111100'
```

The result I would like to achieve would look as follows:

```
 'ATM':
  Plant           Year    Month H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8
  01               1996   Mar   0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1
  02               1997   Feb   0  1  1  1  0  1  1  NA 
  SP               1996   Mar   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  BE               1999   Mar   0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1

'FDA':
 Plant           Year     Month  H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8
  01               2001   Mar    0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
  02               2002   Mar    1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0 
  SP               2001   Apr    1  1  1  0  0  1  1  NA
  BE               2002   June   1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: Sorry, but for me is not clear what you are asking. In particular what you have and what you want to achieve. Can you expand a little, maybe with part of your code?

Comment: I want to split the column Holiday into many columns such that each column has only one "1" or "0" element.

Comment: `01111001` is an invalid syntax. Do you have `0b01111001`? Then this is just an integer printed with a different base. Or you have `"01111001"` that is already a string?

Comment: I have already a string in the column holiday which is actually a combination of a zero or one digit for each day of a month.

Comment: then you can simply obtain your list: `b = "01111001"; a = [ v for v in b ]`

Comment: Sure, but i would like to split the column in each data frame in the dictionary. So suppose the dictionary is called fct_callenders and I try to build the following loop        ` length_calenders= [4,4]                                                                                       for i in range(2):
 for j in range(length_calenders[i]):        
  [int(k) for k in str(fct_calenders_long[names[i]].Holiday[j])] `

Comment: I'm working on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little test code that prints out what you desire. The idea is to use a `numpy` matrix of `str` to store the values. The matrix is full of "NA", thus they will be there at the end. Than the trick uses broadcasting to copy the values in the desired places. The overall data frame is completed through concatenation and deletion of the unneeded column. The code iterates over the keys of your dictionary. I'm assuming you are using `pandas` dataframes, and loaded binary values are interpreted as `object`s.

The first part of the code is an header that constructs the dictionary of data frames.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## Lets call it "header"

from io import StringIO

df_0 = """
Plant;Year;Month;Holiday
01;1996;Mar;01111001
02;1997;Feb;0111011
SP;1996;Mar;01100111
BE;1999;Mar;00111111
"""

df_1 = """
Plant;Year;Month;Holiday
01;2001;Mar;01111101
02;2002;Mar;11110110
SP;2001;Apr;1110011
BE;2002;June;10111100
"""

df_0 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_0), sep=";", dtype=object);
df_1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_1), sep=";", dtype=object);

df = { "ATM": df_0, "PDE": df_1 }

## "Header" end 

MAX_SIZE = 8

for k in df:
  ldf = df[k]
  rows = ldf.shape[1]

  # Here I create a matrix that will contain my required values "NA"
  nmat = np.full((rows, MAX_SIZE), "NA")

  for i in range(rows):
      # I'm using the same conversion that I suggested you in 
      # the comments
      ary = np.array([v for v in ldf["Holiday"][i]])
      # Copying only the needed part, in some cases the final
      # array is of len 7 instead of 8.
      nmat[i, 0:len(ary)] = ary

  # Creating a new dataframe that will be
  # concatenated by using the numpy array generated before.
  nframe = pd.DataFrame(nmat, 
             columns=["H" + str(i+1) for i in range(MAX_SIZE)])
  # Actual concatenation
  ldf = pd.concat([ldf, nframe], axis=1)
  # and deletion on "Holiday" columns
  del ldf["Holiday"]  # only if really needed, removes Holiday column
  # Substitution in the original array
  df[k] = ldf

# et voillà 
print(df)
```

It spits out:

```
{
  'ATM':   
    Plant  Year Month H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7  H8
    0    01  1996   Mar  0  1  1  1  1  0  0   1
    1    02  1997   Feb  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  NA
    2    SP  1996   Mar  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   1
    3    BE  1999   Mar  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1, 
  'PDE':   
    Plant  Year Month H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7  H8
    0    01  2001   Mar  0  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
    1    02  2002   Mar  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
    2    SP  2001   Apr  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  NA
    3    BE  2002  June  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   0
}
```